# AWS SQS message delete on acknowledge with spring cloud aws messaging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

i have SQS queue setup along with consumer and producer, so i have used FIFO queue and once my consumer consume the message, it deletes the message from the queue and then my code perform some operations if any thing failed then i lost the message, so just i want to persist that message in queue and once i give acknowledgement only then delete it. please help me to how to do acknowledgement and delete on basis of acknowledgement.here is my consumer code

````
                                                                                                                                 @SqsListener(value = "${queueName}")
    public void receiveMessage(final msgDTO msgDTO,
                               @Header("SenderId") final String senderId,¸ v) {
        log.info("Received message: {}, having SenderId: {}", msgDTO, senderId);
        // do some operation
        if (operationSuccess) {
            // TODO ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Don't delete the message in your consumer until it finishes those "some operations".

Comment: but msg gets deleted once i consume or timeout but there might be case that until my business logic gets completed its deleted so i have to delete it once i give positive acknowledge to queue for that message to delete, if there is a way out to achieve please help

Comment: Your consumer can extend visibilty timeout. Once you receive the msg, set its visibility timeout to what you need (default is 30 s).

Comment: Sorry man, no i cannot do that my business logic might some time take less time or might take more time but i cannot afford dangling msg over the queue, so i just want to delete only when i give acknowledgemnt

Comment: You cant delete a random msg from the queue at will. SQS does not work like this. Only consumer can do this. If you want to have some other process to delete them, you have to keep pulling the messages in a loop till you get the one you want to remove. So basically you need to have to consumers now.

Comment: @Vishal What you describe the is normal way that Amazon SQS is used. There is a `ReceiveMessage()` command to obtain a message, then there is a `DeleteMessage()` command to tell the queue that the message has been processed. If Spring Boot does not support this separation of functionality, then you should perhaps find a different way to work with Amazon SQS (eg calling it directly).